# Iterating through Datagridview column headers

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Given a DataGridView, I'd like to iterate through datagridivew **column headers**.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in myDataGridView.Columns)
{
   DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell headerCell = column.HeaderCell;
   string headerCaptionText = column.HeaderText;
   string columnName = column.Name; // Used as a key to myDataGridView.Columns['key_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the `DataGridView.Columns` property retrieving its header via the `Name` property as in [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns.aspx). Now, if you have set an associated header cell then you need to use the [HeaderText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.headertext.aspx) property instead.